# Laravel filter nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

So I have three models: Volunteer, Task and Payment. A Volunteer can have many (has many relationship) tasks and a task can have many (another has many relationship) payments.

```
class Volunteer

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}

class Task

  public function volunteer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Volunteer::class);
}

 public function payments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
}

class Payment 

public function task() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Now I want to query all volunteers with unpaid/ partially paid tasks. So, basically I want to filter a volunteer's tasks where each task's amount should equal the sum of all payments linked to that particular task.

I tried using whereHas and with but I don't seem to be able to filter the tasks properly.

I've managed to do it with joins but was wondering if it's possible to with whereHas or with. Below is the code:

```
Volunteer::select('volunteers.id', 'volunteers.name', 'tasks.amount', DB::raw('SUM(payments.amount) as amount_paid'))
        ->join('tasks', 'tasks.volunteer_id', '=', 'volunteers.id')
        ->leftJoin('payments', 'payments.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->groupBy('volunteers.id', 'volunteers.name', 'tasks.amount')
        ->havingRaw('amount_paid >= tasks.amount')
        ->get();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest something else which is adding a column in `tasks` table that indicates if the task is [paid, unpaid or partially paid] in your `tasks` migration like so

```
$table->unsignedTinyInteger('paid_status')->default(0); // 0 -> unpaid, 1 -> partially paid, 2 -> paid
```

then each time the volunteer makes a payments you will do a simple check to update `tasks.paid_status` something like checking the total `paid_amount` and task `amount`

then using Laravel `hasManyThrough` in `Volunteer` model like so

```
public function payments()
{
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
       'App\Payment',
       'App\Task'
  );
}
```

now to get your data you will do so

```
// unpaid tasks
Volunteer::query()->first()->payments()->where('tasks.paid_status', '0')->get();
// partially paid tasks
Volunteer::query()->first()->payments()->where('tasks.paid_status', '1')->get();
// paid tasks
Volunteer::query()->first()->payments()->where('tasks.paid_status', '2')->get();
```

you can read more about HasManyThrough [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Good idea. Was just wondering will it not break the database from being dynamic? As in I'd be hard coding the payment status rather than it calculating itself on the fly. Some advice would be useful.

Comment: No i don't think it will break your database from being dynamic, indeed it's a good practice to do so, speaking of payment status you can make an `PaymentObserver` every time a new payment made you will check `tasks.amount` against `$task->payments()->sum('amount')` then updating `tasks.paid_status` that's a totally dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using the eloquent powers as well. Extends the Task model with a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) method

```php
class Task extends Model
{
    public function volunteer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Volunteer::class);
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }

    public function scopeIncompletePayments($query)
    {
        return $query->select('tasks.*')->leftJoin('payments', 'tasks.id', '=', 'payments.task_id')
            ->having('tasks.amount', '>', DB::raw('SUM(payments.amount)'))
            ->groupBy('tasks.id')
            ->with(['volunteer', 'payments']);
    }
}
```

Which allows you to run the following code to get the tasks where the sum of the related payments is less than the amount of the task. With the payments and Volunteer eagerly loaded

```php
Task::incompletePayments()->get()
```